# JSF converter is not displaying converted value

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2

I am using internet-explorer 8 and jsf.
I made my custom converter that add "\n" after two white spaces (to break too long Strings). Converter is being invoked and return correct value(I check it with debugger) but unfortunately this correct value is not being shown on page. This is xhtml code:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.sort(property)}"
                    style="margin-left:0.01px;margin-right:0.01px;white-space:nowrap;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{header}">
                      <f:converter converterId="headerConverter" />
                    </h:outputText>
</h:commandLink>
```

converter code:

```
public class HeaderConverter implements Converter {

public HeaderConverter() {
}

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    /* Converter tylko do wyświetlania */
    throw new RuntimeException("HeaderConverter - display only");
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value instanceof String) {

        int i = 0;
        int spaceIter = 0;
        String header = (String) value;
        String afterChange = header;

        for (char c : header.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
               spaceIter++;
               if(spaceIter == 2) {
                   afterChange = "" + header.substring(0, i) + "\n" + header.substring(i+1);
               }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return afterChange;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}
Of course I have vonfigured everything on faces-config.xml
Thanks in advance for all your effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. In HTML, newlines are represented by the `<br>` element, not by the `\n` character.

If you rightclick the page in webbrowser and do *View Source*, then you'll see that the `\n` actually made it into the generated HTML output, but is simply not participating in the HTML presentation/formatting.

So, you have 2 options:

1. Use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

   ```
   ... + "<br/>" + ...
   ```

   You only need to turn off XML escaping.

   ```
   <h:outputText ... escape="false" />
   ```

   Beware of potential XSS attack holes when you're redisplaying user-controlled input!
2. Instruct webbrowser to interpret `\n` as part of formatting and not of markup (as default). You can use CSS `white-space: pre` for this.

   ```
   style="white-space: pre;"
   ```